# Want to get back to last Activity after pressing Launcher Icon for my app

Tags: android, android-activity, launcher

Suppose I have an activity A that starts activity B and kills itself. Now I press the Home button (or leave the app some other way) (causing onPause->onStop for activity B) and I click the app icon in the launcher again. What happens is that activity A is started again (of course because I specified that intent-filter in the manifest XML). Is there an easy way to just get back to activity B without starting activity A again? I basically want to get to onStart->onResume in activity B when I reopen the app.

My intent-filter looks like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: when u click home button when ur last visible activity is B, and then relaunch app from launcher activity B's will resume if it was not killed by android else activity A will start.

Comment: @mkso that's not exactly helpful.  OP knows this already.  He wants to always get to activity B.

Comment: I actually just figured out a way but it feels hacky: I keep a static reference in a singleton class of the last activity that was stopped (I clear this in onStart to prevent memory leak). When I activity A is started again, I check this value against null. If it's not null I start an intent with that static variable as target class and with the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT. Feels hacky though.

Comment: @mkso What you're saying is not always true. B will resume if B was only paused. If B was stopped it will actually launch A again. At least in the scenario I was trying.

Comment: @joris onStop() does not mean activity will be pulled out of stack task, which is the case when u click home button assuming activity B was not killed by system after u click device home button activity B's onRestart() followed by onStart() should be called.

Comment: I just ran my app and it does not call onStart() on the last activity. I keep a log of all life-cycle activities. The last activity only gets onStop() and not onDestroy(). After pressing the icon in the launcher, I do not get onStart() from my activity but instead the first Activity is started again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I have a workaround solution.
How about using a transparent activity as the launcher?

When B pause or stop, remember it (in file, db etc.) In the launcher activity, something like a welcome screen but with a transparent view, read the record, and start the recorded activity.

Another solution, but not sure if it works.

Write a broadcast receiver with a launcher filter, and then launch the recorded activity.

Comment: Funny... I came up with similar solution (see comments above). I use a static variable that keeps a reference to the last stopped Activity (I of course clear it timely to prevent leaks). This is essentially your answer.

Comment: Yes, but using durative storages may keep it working even the process is killed. And what I concern is that using a transparent activity (or something like that) seems to make the code a little dirty? Because it's nothing more than a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

One strategy here could be to save a SharedPreference, flagging when you want to go straight to B. [This Android doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) talks about using SharedPreferences, with some code examples.

Essentially, when you want to return straight to B, you create a shared preference indicating this. Then, when A restarts (say, because it was killed by the OS as discussed in the comments on the question), rather than immediately setting the associated view, etc, you first check the flag. If the flag is on, you start B. There is some messiness here, but it could potentially be handled in a very clean way, I think.

Comment: Yep, see comments above. This is what I'm doing. I gave credit to xinthink because he was first (and needs more points :-)