# Android game state save and activity lifecycle

Tags: android

Hello guys I would really appreciate help on a game i am developing.
I have three activities ActivityA,ActivityB and ActivityC.
ActivityA is the main launcher and it runs a thread for some seconds to display the game name, starts activityB and the finishes. A button in ActivityB starts activityC which has the contentview gameboard(SurfaceView). My problem is when I press the home button when playing the game i.e in activityC and then later comes back to the game, the application relaunches from the start(activityA). I would like the application to always come back to the same activity where i pressed the home button. I have read some things about saving the activity states using sharepreferences but but how do i do it since application always relaunches afresh.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706844/want-to-get-back-to-last-activity-after-pressing-launcher-icon-for-my-app/9707230#9707230 is an almost identical question

Comment: @mfrankli thanx. I am going to look through that.